# no unique HTML attribute in a tag with regex

Tags: html, regex

I'm trying to design a regular expression for some time, which checks whether a particular attribute is not present in an HTML tag.

My approach:

1. Finding the HTML tag itself
2. In the tag, all letters are allowed, except those to which the special attrite begins
3. Check whether the so excluded letter only appears to be without the beginning of excluded tags

Specifically: Find all img-tags that do not have the attribute "nosecure".

Here is my current status:
https://regex101.com/r/dR7oQ8/2

(If the link has a Problem, here is my current regex: `/<img([^n]*(?!nosecure))*>/g` )

It seems however, I did not negate the part correctly and now hope that someone can kindly help me here.

Greetings,
Christopher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your negative lookahead assertion like below.

```
<img\b(?![^>]*\bnosecure\b)[^>]*>
```

- `(?![^>]*nosecure)` negative lookahead asserts that there isn't a string `nosecure` exists inside the `img` tag.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dR7oQ8/3)

Comment: wow, that was a very fast answer. thanks :) One question for the understanding: What if I want to make sure, that `nosecure` is also allowed inside a source ore other Tag. So only the Tag key `nosecure` is forbidden, but not the usage inside a value? the `\bnosecure\b` will help me a little, but is there an elegant way to do so?
https://regex101.com/r/dR7oQ8/4